# Summarize crosstab rows horizontally

Tags: crystal-reports

My report is supposed to show raw materials consumed per father item/finished product. The crosstab looks as follows:

```
------------------------RM1-------------------RM2--------------------RM3

Father 1 ------------CONSUMED--------------CONSUMED---------------CONSUMED

Father 2 ------------CONSUMED--------------CONSUMED---------------CONSUMED

Father 3 ------------CONSUMED--------------CONSUMED---------------CONSUMED
```

How can I show the consumed total of each father in the row next to it? Basically I need a formula that sums all the consumed rows horizontally, per father and not per RM1. I have only managed to sum per column and not per raw.

Comment: easy way is to just pivot the cross tab

Comment: True i'd then be able to just use the default totals, but i've put that as a last resort as the layout i mentioned is a requirement.